# Set input's 'value' attribute from data?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a string coming in from the server named 'email'. In my pug template I'd like to set the initial value of an input field, but it renders literally as '#{email}' instead of the actual email address. If I remove the quotation marks, the pug file throws an error.

```
input(type='text' id='eMailAddress' value='#{email}')
```

On the server-side:

```
res.render('personal-details', {email:req.session.email})
```

How can I set the value dynamically?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Comment: I have added rest of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using pug version 2+, you can do the following…

```
input#eMailAddress(type='text' value=email)
```

Comment: awesome! thanks! it's weird, all I had to do was move the ID attribute outside of the () brackets?!